# Google Play Api defaults to "only me" when using "Google Play API Client Library for Java"

Tags: java, google-play-services, google-play-games

Google+ App visibility keeps switching to "only me" making Leaderboards have no scores.

I am using the Google Play Developer API Client Library for Java from the following link in a Desktop, Android, and iOS project:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

Everything works fine in testing and production in regards to API calls succeeding. The only issue seems to be that within the last month the "visibility" settings have switched up and I can't find any information on why this should be...

If I set the apps visibility to "public" manually in Google+ then logout and logon with the app, the visibility is reset to "only me".

The app is requesting the following scopes:

```
/** View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive. */
  public static final String DRIVE_APPDATA = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata";

  /** Share your Google+ profile information and view and manage your game activity. */
  public static final String GAMES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games";

  /** Know your basic profile info and list of people in your circles.. */
  public static final String PLUS_LOGIN = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
```

I am using the latest versions of the libraries. The scopes come directly from the GamesScopes.java file which are a part of the libraries.

Drive access to user specific appdata works fine.

For those curious, the desktop version of the app is available from:
 - http://www.cherokeelessons.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=73&p=240#p274

and the android version of the app is available from:
 - https://community.testfairy.com/join/zlth1UtJ

Comment: You can find many samples of `google api java client` from [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples) about Google +. Check it out to see if it works.

Comment: The API is being used based on those samples already. It does not explain why the settings are defaulting to "only me".